# docker-compose alternate file will not pick up .env in that directory

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm using one of the ELK (Elastic Search, Logstach, and Kibana) stack using a pre created docker-compose.yml from [github](https://github.com/deviantony/docker-elk). When I'm in the cloned directory and do `docker-compose up` everything works fine. It picks up the *ELK_VERSION=6.4.0* from the *.env* file in same directory as the *docker-compose.yml*.

However, if I for example go one directory up and specify the compose file with full path it will not pick up the *.env* file.
`docker-compose -f "C:\progs\docker\docker-elk\docker-compose.yml" up`. It will just complain that *ELK_VERSION* is not set.

I have also tried to set the *project directory* with no luck. `docker-compose -f "C:\progs\docker\docker-elk\docker-compose.yml" --project-directory "C:\progs\docker\docker-elk" up`.

I'm clueless what do to except doing a

```
$ cd <elk compose dir>
$ docker-compose up
$ cd -
```

But that is not safe for my little OSS library [FluentDocker](https://github.com/mariotoffia/FluentDocker). I want the user to at all times have full control of `CurrentDirectory`.

Version: *docker-compose version 1.22.0, build f46880fe*

Cheers,
 Mario

Comment: Thanks! It works like a charm :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Official doc says](https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/)

> Compose supports declaring default environment variables in an
>   environment file named .env placed in the folder where the
>   docker-compose **command is executed** (current working directory).

If you move the .env file to the folder that you execute the docker-compose it should work.